# Excel-Dragging a Formula using multiple worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to enter an equation in worksheet 2 of `A1+A2` (from worksheet 1) and be able to copy the equation down so I end up with `A1+A2`, `A3+A4`, `A5+A6`.  So the first cell on Sheet2 has the sum of the first two cells on Sheet1, the second has the sum of the 3rd and 4th, and so on.

How do I enter this equation in the first cell and be able to drag the equation down without having to enter each equation in separately?

Comment: That _sounds_ like the default behavior of Excel.  Suppose Cell A1 of Sheet2 has `=Sheet1!A1+Sheet1!A2`.  I enter that and drag down (grabbing the little black handle at the bottom right corner.  Excel fills in with automatic adjustments so that Sheet2!A2 has `=Sheet1!A2+Sheet1!A3`, Sheet2!A3 has `=Sheet1!A3+Sheet1!A4` and so on.  What are you trying to do that is different from this?

Comment: @Adam - I thought the same, but notice what she's asking: first `A1+A2`, then `A3+A4`.  The default behavior would just increase each row by 1 - Carrie wants to skip row 2, and go to row 3 (A **3** +A **4** ) in the second instance. Then in the third, skip row 4 and go to `A5+A6`.

Answer (score 1):

Enter this in `Sheet2!A1`, and drag down:

`=OFFSET(Sheet1!A1,ROW()-1,0)+OFFSET(Sheet1!A1,ROW(),0)`

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.  Since you seem to know a lot, I wonder if you can help me with another equation.  Same kind of scenario.  I'm using informaiton from sheet within my workbook to flood information to andother sheet, but I want to skip rows.  So  Sheet 2 A1 = Sheet 1 (A1), Sheet 2 A2 = Sheet 1 A3, Sheet 2 A3 = Sheet 1 A5.  How do I accomplish in an equation?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
=SUM(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,(ROW(1:1)-1)*2+1):INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,ROW(1:1)*2))
```

Comment: Is this an alternative to what I posted, or is mine not considering something? (Just curious!)

Comment: Yours will not do what the OP wants as is.  At row 2 it will sum A2 and A3 where the OP want A3 and A4  So you will need to do some more math with yours: `=OFFSET(Sheet1!A1,(ROW()-1)*2,0)+OFFSET(Sheet1!A1,ROW()*2,0)` @BruceWayne

Comment: Hm, then why did my quick test seem to give the right answer? (I am sure you're right, I'm just trying to see where I'm going wrong or what I'm overlooking).  See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUmOi.jpg).

Comment: Never mind, I did not notice that your A1 is relative, so it moves down so in row 2 it offset 1 and 2 from A2 not A1 effectively doin what it should.  I read it as anchored on A1 only.  Your formula works, but mine works **AND** is not volatile. 8P  @BruceWayne

Comment: Haha, thanks for confirming I'm not crazy, but good point about the volatility.  :D